# CoreTelephony crash

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, crash, core-telephony

I am receiving this backtrace from `TestFlight` regarding one interesting crash.

As far as I understood, the application crashes at some point, when using `CoreTelephony`. Can this be possible of someone "calling" while the user is using the application?

To my knowledge, the application is not using the `CoreTelephony Framework`. The Exception reason is `SIGSEGV` and the crash thread is 0

Thank You!

```
PRIMARY THREAD THREAD 0

0 GPIreland 0x00113a1a testflight_backtrace + 238
1 GPIreland 0x00114704 TFSignalHandler + 264
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x359d1e92 _sigtramp + 42
3 CoreTelephony 0x330078b4 <redacted> + 32
4 CoreFoundation 0x333465de __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 14
5 CoreFoundation 0x33346290 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 272
6 CoreFoundation 0x33344f00 __CFRunLoopRun + 1232
7 CoreFoundation 0x332b7ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
8 CoreFoundation 0x332b7d48 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
9 GraphicsServices 0x3b0b52ea GSEventRunModal + 74
10 UIKit 0x3ab732f8 UIApplicationMain + 1120
11 GPIreland 0x00036f8a main (main.m:4)
12 GPIreland 0x0000d5a7 start + 39
Hide Other Threads

COM.APPLE.NSURLCONNECTIONLOADER

0 CoreFoundation 0x33344da2 __CFRunLoopRun + 882
1 CoreFoundation 0x332b7ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
2 CoreFoundation 0x332b7d48 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
3 Foundation 0x34ed7bcc +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 308
4 Foundation 0x34f5b67c __NSThread__main__ + 972
5 libsystem_c.dylib 0x359aa310 _pthread_start + 308
6 libsystem_c.dylib 0x359aa1d7 thread_start + 7
COM.APPLE.CFSOCKET.PRIVATE

0 libsystem_c.dylib 0x359aa1d7 thread_start + 7
THREAD 10

0 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3599f8a3 start_wqthread + 7
THREAD 11

0 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3599f8a3 start_wqthread + 7
WEBTHREAD

0 CoreFoundation 0x33344da2 __CFRunLoopRun + 882
1 CoreFoundation 0x332b7ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
2 CoreFoundation 0x332b7d48 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
3 WebCore 0x37613a44 <redacted> + 444
4 libsystem_c.dylib 0x359aa310 _pthread_start + 308
5 libsystem_c.dylib 0x359aa1d7 thread_start + 7
THREAD 8

0 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3599f8a3 start_wqthread + 7
THREAD 12

0 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3599f8a3 start_wqthread + 7
THREAD 1

0 CoreLocation 0x39148d26 <redacted> + 350
1 CoreLocation 0x3917f072 <redacted> + 346
2 libxpc.dylib 0x349377e8 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 772
3 libdispatch.dylib 0x35970df8 _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke$VARIANT$up + 124
4 libdispatch.dylib 0x3596095c _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$up + 84
5 libdispatch.dylib 0x3597106e _dispatch_mach_invoke$VARIANT$up + 154
6 libdispatch.dylib 0x3596095c _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$up + 84
7 libdispatch.dylib 0x35960894 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$up + 36
8 libdispatch.dylib 0x3596095c _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$up + 84
9 libdispatch.dylib 0x35960894 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$up + 36
10 libdispatch.dylib 0x3596f214 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 192
11 libdispatch.dylib 0x3596f3b8 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 84
12 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3599fa10 _pthread_wqthread + 360
13 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3599f8a3 start_wqthread + 7
THREAD 2

0 0xffffffff 0xffffffff
THREAD 3

0 libdispatch.dylib 0x3596f258 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 260
1 libdispatch.dylib 0x3596f3b8 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 84
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3599fa10 _pthread_wqthread + 360
3 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3599f8a3 start_wqthread + 7
THREAD 6

0 CoreLocation 0x391491f0 <redacted> + 136
1 CoreLocation 0x3918065c <redacted> + 36
2 CoreLocation 0x3917efee <redacted> + 214
3 libxpc.dylib 0x34930b40 do_mach_notify_port_destroyed + 160
4 libxpc.dylib 0x34930a9a _Xmach_notify_port_destroyed + 126
5 libxpc.dylib 0x34930a16 notify_server + 90
6 libxpc.dylib 0x3493789c _xpc_connection_mach_event + 952
7 libdispatch.dylib 0x35970df8 _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke$VARIANT$up + 124
8 libdispatch.dylib 0x3596095c _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$up + 84
9 libdispatch.dylib 0x3597106e _dispatch_mach_invoke$VARIANT$up + 154
10 libdispatch.dylib 0x3596095c _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$up + 84
11 libdispatch.dylib 0x35960894 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$up + 36
12 libdispatch.dylib 0x3596095c _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$up + 84
13 libdispatch.dylib 0x35960894 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$up + 36
14 libdispatch.dylib 0x3596f214 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 192
15 libdispatch.dylib 0x3596f3b8 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 84
16 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3599fa10 _pthread_wqthread + 360
17 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3599f8a3 start_wqthread + 7
THREAD 7

0 CoreFoundation 0x33344da2 __CFRunLoopRun + 882
1 CoreFoundation 0x332b7ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
2 CoreFoundation 0x332b7d48 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
3 Foundation 0x34eae78e -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 254
4 Foundation 0x34f5205c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 80
5 GPIreland 0x0012999c -[TFNetworkManager networkRunLoopThreadEntry] + 124
6 Foundation 0x34f5b67c __NSThread__main__ + 972
7 libsystem_c.dylib 0x359aa310 _pthread_start + 308
8 libsystem_c.dylib 0x359aa1d7 thread_start + 7
LOAD ADDRESS

0x0000b000

REGISTER VALUES

cpsr: 536870960
exception: 0
far: 2180846006
fsr: 7
lr: 855668917
pc: 874685872
r0: 534160688
r1: 855823900
r10: 999295808
r11: 534104888
r12: 998755496
r2: 0
r3: 534160688
r4: 2180845998
r5: 534381712
r6: 534465568
r7: 803163884
r8: 854411733
r9: 213955975
sp: 803163868
```

Comment: Did you add your .DSYM file to testflight in the Crashes section? Once you do that it will symbolicate your crash reports and give you better info about it, and maybe even a line number. Testflight has good instructions on how to do this

Comment: Yes, I have added .DSYM and that's what the testflight is giving me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT**: There is a fix for this bug in sdk 1.3.0-beta.2 available here: https://testflightapp.com/sdk/download/

I work at TestFlight. We have just recently discovered this bug. It is an iOS bug with CoreTelephony. The TestFlight SDK uses CoreTelephony. So this will sometimes cause crashes. We have a fix that is going to be ready very soon. It will be included in the next beta (probably 1.3.0-beta.2). I'm very sorry for the trouble!

Jason

More information on the crash for those interested:

There is an iOS bug that causes instances of the `CTTelephonyNetworkInfo` class to sometimes get notifications after they have been deallocated. Instead of instantiating, using, and releasing instances you must instead retain and never release them to work around the bug.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, I have struggled quite a lot to find what was wrong.

Comment: I'm very sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: I'm having similar issue in my app. Can you share some more detail on how you are sidestepping this bug? Is it basically just storing CTTelephonyNetworkInfo in a static variable? Something like this:

 `static CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *netInfo;
    static dispatch_once_t dispatchToken;
    if (!netInfo)
    {
        dispatch_once(&dispatchToken, ^{
            netInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
        });
    }`

Comment: @KirbyTodd yup! sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Do you know whether `CTTelephonyNetworkInfo` is thread-safe (if not then a single instance cannot be used across threads)?

Comment: Is there a radar for that apple bug? Has it been resolved since?